# CountIfs date range AND conditional, possibly a VBA solution

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Okay, so here is a sample my current code. I have this in several cells , where B-H7 reflect the absence type it is searching for.

```
=COUNTIFS('Old Data'!$A:$A,Tracking!A8,'Old Data'!$B:$B,$E$7, 'Old Data'!D:D, ">"&$B$5, 'Old Data'!D:D, "<"&$C$5)
```

What this code is doing is looping through a spreadsheet, where the employee name is found in the data sheet, comparing the absence types and assorting them to their respective columns and counting them, the last bit of code restricts the search between date ranges.

That being said, I need to add conditions to this that I'm not sure I can without taking it into VBA. In the "Old Data" Sheet in column D I have start time, which displays in MM/DD/YY HH:MM format.  In Column E I have End Time, which displays in the same MM/DD/YY HH:MM format.

I need to have a way to

A.) Have the progam count the number of days between these dates and a +1 to the count for each respective day.

B.) If the start and end date are the same, have the program compare the number hours. if it is less than 4, only add a .5 to the counter.

My first thought is to scratch the countifs formula and loop through and parse it out using VBA, but I thought I'd check first to see if it can be done with just the formula as the power of the built in function has been pretty surprising to me so far.

I think I should probably take this from a formula to a VBA function and call it in the cells, but I'm not entirely sure, pretty new to the VBA/Excel scene.

Also, I'm in Excel 2007.

Thanks for any input on this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *possible* to do with a formula but not with COUNTIFS. This array formula should do it

`=SUM(IF(('Old Data'!$A$2:$A$100=Tracking!A8)*('Old Data'!$B$2:$B$100=$E$7)*('Old Data'!$D$2:$D$100>$B$5)*('Old Data'!$D$2:$D$100<$C$5),IF('Old Data'!$E$2:$E$100-'Old Data'!$D$2:$D$100<"4:00"+0,0.5,INT('Old Data'!$E$2:$E$100)-INT('Old Data'!$D$2:$D$100)+1)))`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

I restricted the data range to rows 2 to 100, adjust as required, whole columns is possible but that may slow down the formula considerably

To count workdays only change to this version:

`=SUM(IF(('Old Data'!$A$2:$A$100=Tracking!A8)*('Old Data'!$B$2:$B$100=$E$7)*('Old Data'!$D$2:$D$100>$B$5)*('Old Data'!$D$2:$D$100<$C$5),IF('Old Data'!$E$2:$E$100-'Old Data'!$D$2:$D$100<"4:00"+0,0.5,NETWORKDAYS('Old Data'!$D$2:$D$100+0,'Old Data'!$E$2:$E$100+0))))`

You can also exclude holidays if you add a holiday range to the NETWORKDAYS function

Comment: Is it possilbe to have go through any number of rows? The list is currently 1600, and forever being added to. Current formula simply returns FALSE

Comment: also whats the * represent in your formula?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem to change the 100 to 10000 for example, for future expansion, I would avoid full column as 1 million rows will cause the formula to be slow, * in array formulas is effectively an "AND" condition (you can use multiple IFs as an alternative). Make sure you "array enter" the formula - put in cell, press F2 then hold down CTRL and SHIFT keys and press ENTER so that curly braces like { and } appear around formula in formula bar

Comment: If it reached a million I'd be highly surprised, I'm creating a program to help out my boss.  likely it won't be used mroe than a year or too, if I were to take it back to A! would it still work?

Comment: using A:A etc will work but with this sort of formula that's not advisable (COUNTIFS can reference a whole column like A:A but in fact it will only look at the used cells, that isn't the case here), as I say probably best to use a range which allows some expansion (another alternative is to use dynamic ranges)

Comment: Okay, well thank you very much sir! This does in fact work and answer my question, all I have to do yet is test the .5 aspect of it. I do have one other question, if you have the time. in another cell I use '=Allotments!$B2 - COUNTIFS('Old Data'!$A:$A,Tracking!A8,'Old Data'!$B:$B,$B$7, 'Old Data'!D:D, ">"&$B$5, 'Old Data'!D:D, "<"&$C$5)' Basically my old code subtracted from another cell. can I apply the same logic to the code you provided, and can you explain how the {} array works?

Comment: @Floppityflip If you want to avoid using the entire column reference, but don't want to manually update the formula each time, try using a [dynamic defined range](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830287). It also makes your formulas more readable! :)

Comment: Yes you can subtract my suggested formula from another value, that would still be an "array formula" though - Chip Pearson explains in this link http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx

Comment: Thanks guys, I really appreicate the help!

Comment: @barry houdini  Last question. Is it possible to use the workday function inside this array formula and ignore weekends?

Comment: Hey Barry, so I'm error checking my code, and if there is an absence on a friday and saturday that is < 4 hours it returns two absences, and I beleive its due to the fact that networkdays is after the actual < 4:00 logic. I tried putting it in front but its not accept any of the syntax, was wondering if you could shed some more light on the issue